# Does how you discard a Madness card affect whether it resolve before its source?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Take two possible sources of discard, [Sinister Concoction](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sinister%20Concoction) and [Macabre Waltz](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Macabre%20Waltz). One has a discard as part of the cost, one has a discard as part of the effect.

In the first case (discard as part of the cost), if you discard a madness card, will it resolve **before** the source ability?
In the second case (discard as part of the ability), will the madness card resolve **after** the source ability?

Comment: That title is incomprehensible.

Comment: I think the difference here depends on how you look at it. In the first case, you discard as part of activating the ability, so madness triggers after you activate the ability. In the second case, you discard as part of resolving the spell, so madness triggers after you resolve the spell.

Comment: @Hackworth Do you have a suggestion for the title?  Or should it just be the more generic: Does a Madness spell resolve before the ability that caused it to be discarded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes to both questions.**

Madness is a two-part keyword ability:

> 702.34a Madness is a keyword that represents two abilities. The first is a static ability that functions while the card with madness is in a player’s hand. The second is a triggered ability that functions when the first ability is applied. “Madness [cost]” means “If a player would discard this card, that player discards it, but exiles it instead of putting it into his or her graveyard” and “When this card is exiled this way, its owner may cast it by paying [cost] rather than paying its mana cost. If that player doesn’t, he or she puts this card into his or her graveyard.”

If you discard a Madness card as part of the costs of a spell or ability, the Madness trigger will be on top of the spell or ability that had the discard cost, because putting that spell or ability on the stack is always the very first step, before costs are paid:

> 601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect. [..]]
>
> 602.2. To activate an ability is to put it onto the stack and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect.

If the discard happens as part of the effect of a spell or ability, it can obviously only happen after that spell or ability has resolved, not before. The Madness trigger goes on the stack immediately after resolution of that spell or ability.

Comment: Nit: in the second case, the Madness trigger goes on the stack *immediately after* the resolution of the spell or ability [CR 603.3].